# convergence in probability of the average

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question: Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables satisfying that $X_n$ converge in probability to $0$, so what happened to the new sequence $(Y_n)_n$?

where

$$Y_n=\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots X_n}{n}$$

Dose $Y_n$ converges in probability to $0$?

Comment: Have you thought about the equivalent statement for sequences in real analysis? Your sequence Y_n is the Cesaro mean, and you might want to look at the proof that convergence of a sequence implies convergence of the Cesaro mean.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X_j$ taking only two values: $0$ and $2^j$ with probability $\frac 1j$. Then 
$$\mu\{Y_n\geqslant 1\}=\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=\log_2n}^n\{X_j\neq 0\}\right).$$

Comment: Do you have any idea, e.g., under what conditions, that statement "$Y_n$  converges in probability to 0" holds?